# How many carbons does an alkane need to have an enantiomer?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality

How many carbon atoms does an alkane need before it is capable of existing in enantiomeric forms?

Answer (score 6):

If we allow our substituents to be isotopes, then 2 is all that is really necessary:

$\hspace{6cm}$[image: isotopes]

If we exclude such compounds from consideration, then cyclopropanes will give you smallest number of carbons at 5:

$\hspace{5.5cm}$[image: cyclopropanes]

---

As a side note, for a non-alkane, only 1 carbon is necessary:

$\hspace{5.7cm}$[image: bromochlorofluoromethane]

Comment: If we were not confined to saturated compounds, I'd suggest 1,3-dimethyl allene.

Comment: Also, come to think of it, carbon is not necessary _at all_.

Answer (score 5):

If you are only looking for *alkanes*, of the form $\ce{C_nH_{2n+2}}$, with no isotopic substitution, then the most logical way is to think back to the definition of a chiral carbon. The IUPAC Gold Book [writes](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00479.html):

> The traditional name for a carbon atom that is attached to four different entities...

So, start with a carbon in the middle.

[image]

The smallest substituent you can put on this carbon is hydrogen (zero carbons). The next-smallest is a methyl (one carbon), and after that you need to use an ethyl group (two carbons).

[image]

For the last group, you need to use three carbons, because there is no other two-carbon alkyl substituent apart from the ethyl group. So, you could use a *n*-propyl group (only one isomer depicted here)

[image]

or an isopropyl group (again only one isomer depicted)

[image]